# What's the preferable way of iterating over a small fixed number of values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, iteration

I want to some code block for a fixed number of variables, say:

```
MyGenericClass<T> v1,v2,v3;
/* ... */
{
    /* something with v1 */
}
{
    /* same thing with v2 */
}
{
    /* same thing with v3 */
}
```

I want to avoid the code duplication. What's the best way to do this (and hopefully, not creating objects for GC, as this code gets run a lot)?

This works:

```
for (MyGenericClass<S> v : new MyGenericClass[] {v1,v2,v3}) {
    /* something with v - no casting */
}
```

with a type safety warning, as does this:

```
for (MyGenericClass<S> v : Arrays.asList(v1,v2,v3) {
    /* something with v - no casting */
}
```

Which one of these should I prefer? And there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

This would be my way of doing it:

```
MyGenericClass<T> v1,v2,v3;
   foo(v1);
   foo(v2);
   foo(v3);
}
private void foo(MyGenericClass<T> v)
{
    /* something with v */
}
```

You solutions will create extra objects (the first one will create an array, the second an array, a list and an iterator). My function call will get inlined by the compiler if it is called a lot, and the references will be stored on the stack rather than in the heap.

Comment: Ah, you're assuming the only thing I'm using is v1...v3. I'm using a bunch of other local variables which I would have to pass, and I already have too many methods, and the method name would be kind of cryptic... but, yeah, in many cases a function is obviously best.

Comment: You are not going to make your code less cryptic by making the methods longer and wrapping your local variables in lists...

Comment: Of course I do not propose you name your method `foo`! I have no idea what the code does so there is no way I can name it correctly. The point is that you should make a method call because this is obviously what you need and in terms of performance that is the best you can do...

Comment: It'd have to be `frobnicateTheBarForSpecificBazesGivenThisAndThatButNotTheOtherCondition(VeryVeryLongClassName1 longInstanceName1, VeryVeryLongClassName2 longInstanceName2, VeryVeryLongClassName3 longInstanceName3,... , MyGenericClass<T> v)`

Comment: Great. Then you have both the solution and a name for it :-)

Comment: @eyalroz If such a private method do not work for you, than you should reconsider your architecture at all. It seems you have to much logic in that class. Maybe you should split you code into a data and an algorithm class.